# Problemas para hacer que number (Angular 5) acepte decimales con coma

Tags: angular5

Hola tengo el siguiente problema, necesito que al asignar a una variable del tipo number un numero con decimales con coma (Ej 10,50) no me quede en NaN, de momento solo me acepta decimales con punto (Ej 10.50) pero en mi país las comas se usan para separar decimales y los puntos para los miles (Ej 1.000.000,00).

Hay alguna forma de hacer que number use coma para los decimales?

Gracias

Comment: No, porque es una especificación del lenguaje. Es como intentar usar `si (a==1) {...} en-otro-caso {...}` y esperar que compile. Tendrás que sustituir en el String las comas por puntos y luego hacer la transformación a `Number`

Comment: Angular tiene opciones como getLocaleNumberFormat (https://angular.io/api/common/getLocaleNumberFormat) que tengo entendido que permite elegir el formato del number pero no entiendo bien como implementarlo para hacer lo que necesito.

Comment: Son dos cosas distintas: como te comento puedes crearte una función (o usar una existente) que te haga la transformación, pero no se puede hacer un parseFloat('123,45') directamente

Comment: Como  @PabloLozano te comenta es la especificación del lenguaje, lo que se hace es internamente se maneja con punto y en la presentación se utiliza el `DecimalPipe` para mostrar el formato según la region, aparte te recomiendo que agregues código mostrando como quieres realizar la transformación y de donde obtienes el la cantidad separada por comas.

Answer (score 0):

La solución podría ser la creación de un Pipe para que puedas usar la variable con '**.**' pero visualizarlo con '**,**'. Así no se rompería por usar otro formato.

En el transform() del pipe la variable se pasa a *string* y retorna con replace('.', ',');

```
 import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

/**
 * Pipe name
 * @export
 * @class CurrencyCustom
 * @implements {PipeTransform}
 */
@Pipe({
    name: 'CurrencyCustom'
})
export class CurrencyCustom implements PipeTransform {
    /**
     * Convierte una cantidad separada por punto a coma.
     * @param {number} currency 9999.99
     * @returns {string} '9999,99'
     */
    transform(currency: number): string {
        return currency.toString().replace(/./g, ',');
    }
}
```